# Passing php-variable with JavaScript and HTML-Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I am trying to create a Delete-button with a user confirmation-pop-up.

HTML/PHP:

```
<form method='POST' onclick='return confirmDelete()'>
  <button type='submit'>
    Delete script
  </button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmDelete() {
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
  window.location.href = 'delete_script.php?<?php echo "$id" ?>';
  return false;
}
else{
  return true;
  }
}
</script>
```

What it does is that it re-directs me to the correct page, "delete_script.php" **but the $id does not appear in the url**. The "delete_script.php"-page works with other pages, but I don't know what's wrong with this code. I really think it's possible. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This looks od <?php echo "$id" ?>. If $id is a variable remove the double quotes. You also might want to add a query string name for example 'delete_script.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>'.

Comment: You could just keep it in a $_SESSION[''] varible... that way it's global... everywhere .

Comment: Where does `$id` come from in the first place?

Comment: I did try to keep it in a $_SESSION variable, but it wouldn't get into the url anyway. And I'd prefer to do it this way. I have excluded alot of code, the $id is the id of a post in my database. This page gets it from $_GET from another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expected to pass a url-encoded value for the query-string:

```
<?php echo 'id=' . urlencode($id); ?>
```

Alternatively, generate the whole url in php:

```
location.href = <?php echo json_encode('delete_script.php?id=' . urlencode($id)); ?>;
```

Comment: The alternative answer worked perfectly! Thank you very much, sir.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, change this...

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
  window.location.href = 'delete_script.php?<?php echo "$id" ?>';
  return false;
}
```

to this..

```
if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
  window.location.href = 'delete_script.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>';
  return false;
}
```

Comment: No difference, thanks though. Just re-directing me to the page without any $id in the url.